# Fetching all the addresses falling within a radius using Google map api V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project which requires to fetch all the addresses falling within a specified radius using google map api. 
I tried this with Google map Nearby places api but it results only few places of type given, instead I want it to return all the addresses within that area.

Is there any way to accomplish this using google map api only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nearby search gives maximum 20 results. You can try **radarSearch** for more results.[You can check example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search)

Comment: I want all the addresses. radarSearch just give few results that to scattered ones. Is there any other way to do ?